# Show class div and hide previous - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, show-hide

I was actually using a script which allowed me to Show a div onclick and hide others but now I need to do the same with "class" instead of "id".

My current script:

```
function layout(divName){
var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("tempDivName");
if(hiddenVal.Value != undefined){
    var oldDiv = document.getElementById(hiddenVal.Value); 
    oldDiv.style.display = 'none'; 
}

var tempDiv = document.getElementById(divName); 
tempDiv.style.display = 'block';              

hiddenVal.Value = document.getElementById(divName).getAttribute("class");}
```

What I tried using getElementsByClassName :

```
function layoutNEW(divName){
var hiddenVal = document.getElementById("tempDivName");
if(hiddenVal.Value != undefined){
    var oldDiv = document.getElementById(hiddenVal.Value); 
    oldDiv.style.display = 'none'; 
}
var tempDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(divName);
for ( var i=0, len=tempDiv.length; i<len; ++i ){
    tempDiv[i].style.display = 'block';  
}
hiddenVal.Value = document.getElementById(divName).getAttribute("id");}
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :** A working example of my current script with "id" : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5v3v6nr)

**EDIT 2:** It works great, but when the div (class) is cloned, only one of them is showing the div. Do you have an idea about this ? Where is a JSFiddle demonstrating the situation: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5v3v6nr)

Comment: Are you clicking on a `div` or on some other element to hide/show? Can you share your html as well as the rest of your JavaScript?

Comment: what is `.Value`? Why does it have a capital V? Why don't you just find the element that was clicked (event.target) and than hide the rest?

Comment: @epascarello You can't hide the rest of the elements on click, otherwise you wouldn't be able to click on another element. You would hide the clicked element and show the rest.

Comment: @mhodges or whatever the OP is doing.... the code that OP has makes no sense.

Comment: @epascarello 100% agreed. No need to store any values in a hidden element, you can access the event trigger with event.target, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you'd need. The idea is that you can use a data property on your `<a>` tags that will tell your click handler which classname to look for when showing an element. From there, you just hide the others. Here's a working demo:

```js
var toggleControls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-trigger]");
var contentDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < toggleControls.length; i++) {
  toggleControls[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var trigger = event.target;
    var selector = "." + trigger.getAttribute("data-trigger");
    var divToShow = document.querySelector(selector);
    for (j = 0; j < contentDivs.length; j++) {
      contentDivs[j].style.display = "none";
    }
    divToShow.style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.div3 {
  background-color: purple;
}
.div4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-trigger="div1">Show Div1</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" data-trigger="div2">Show Div2</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" data-trigger="div3">Show Div3</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" data-trigger="div4">Show Div4</a>
<div class="toggle-container">
  <div class="toggle div1"></div>
  <div class="toggle div2"></div>
  <div class="toggle div3"></div>
  <div class="toggle div4"></div>
</div>
```

## EDIT - As per updated question

In order to get this to work with dynamically created elements, you will have to put the `var contentDivs = ...` inside of the click handler, so you get a live version of that array. Also, you will need to change `.querySelector` to `.querySelectorAll` as the former only grabs the first matching element, not all as the latter does.

Here's what the code would look like: (note - I also moved the click handler into an outside function so it was not being recreated for every iteration of the loop, as is good practice)

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle"); // get live set of contentDivs in case any were added dynamically
    var trigger = event.target;
    var selector = "." + trigger.getAttribute("data-trigger");
    var divsToShow = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // grab all matching divs
    for (var i = 0; i < contentDivs.length; i++) {
        contentDivs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < divsToShow.length; j++) {
        divsToShow[j].style.display = "block";
    }
}
var toggleControls = document.querySelectorAll("[data-trigger]");
for (var i = 0; i < toggleControls.length; i++) {
  toggleControls[i].addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}


function cloneDiv() {                
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

  for ( var i=0; i<elmnt.length; i++ ) {
    var cln = elmnt[i].cloneNode(true);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(cln);
  document.getElementById("clone").appendChild(cln);
}
window.onload = cloneDiv();
```

Comment: It's almost what I need, but it has to be "switch" when clicking on an external button. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/we2AJ/

Comment: @Leshautsdurant Try it now, I think that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you very much  this is perfect even cleaner than my previous script !

Comment: It works great, but when the div (class) is cloned, only one of them is showing the div.

Do you have an idea about this ?
Where is a JSFiddle demonstrating the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/e5v3v6nr/

Comment: @Leshautsdurant Updated my post: have a look